# Print value from PHP key value pair

Tags: php, json, key-value

I have a key/value pair passed from Javascript via `$.post` as `data : user_id`.

I've brought it into PHP with `$data = $_POST['data']` and when I `vardump()` that I get `{"id":"1"}"` as expected. However, I'd like to just access the value of `1`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just JSON. Use `json_decode()` to turn it into an object (or an array if you so choose) and then get the value of ID using standard object member variable access methods:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
echo $data->id;
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sZjSkn)

If you're using PHP 5.4+ (using array syntax and array dereferencing):

```
echo json_decode('{"id":"1"}', true)['id'];
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jAbxq8)

Comment: That did it. Thanks for that - and the explanation. Will accept when I can.

Comment: +1 didn't know that I can now directly access the resulting array of a function in php 5.4+. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true)['id']
```